# Displaying XHTML elements with namespaces in .NET WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xhtml

I have an XML document that contains in one element XHTML fragments, specifically one or more **p** tags, which can contain further XHTML tags such as **em**, **span** etc. These are all in an "xhtml" namespace, and the XSD has imported the XHTML strict schema, so all is fine in that regard. My problem is this:

My application needs to display these XHTML paragraphs as a document. My thought was to wrap these in an XHTML document with a namespace specified on the body tag, like this:

```
<!-- Stock XHTML pre-amble from application -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" 
        content="application/xhtml+xml;charset=utf-16" />
</head>
<body xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <!-- Elements from XML document -->
  <xhtml:p>Namespaced paragraph from XML</xhtml:p>  
  <xhtml:p>A partly <xhtml:em>italicised</xhtml:em> paragraph from XML</xhtml:p>
<!-- Post-amble -->
</body> 
</html>
```

This way, I wouldn't have to remove all namespaces from the XHTML elements when putting the document together.

While this displays correctly in Firefox, if I save it as a file, in the System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control (.NET 3.0), the two paragraphs flow together and the **em** is ignored (the same thing occurs in IE8). In other words, the WebBrowser doesn't unserstand the namespace, and treats **xhtml:p** as an unknown element.

I'm curious from a purely academic point of view whether Firefox or IE8 is in the right here, but am more interested in a pragmatic solution to this problem, if one exists.

Comment: When you say it displays correctly in Firefox, how are you testing it?

Comment: I save the generated document (similar to above example, but with much larger content) as a file with .html extension and open it in IE and FF. In IE the paragraphs flow together, as if they were not enclosed in any tags, while in FF they are on separate lines with normal paragraph distance. I do not know if this is correct from a purely specification-legal point of view, but it's what I expect and want. I haven't tested on other browsers since I'm really only concerned with displaying this in a C#/.NET desktop GUI.

Comment: What you see in IE is the correct behaviour, modulo you've no doctype so it's not clear what "correct" actually is. But I can't reproduce what you see in Firefox without using a `.xhmtl` extension.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 doesn't support "real" XHTML, so your elements with a colon in them aren't in a namespace at all. In fact, if you inspect the DOM in IE8, you'll see that the elements aren't even wrapping the text properly.

I suspect the same goes for the WebBrowser control.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I guess that means I'll have to strip out the namespace as part of the wrapping.